# difference between mult, multu simulating in c

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I'm writing a c program and decodes mips 32 bit instructions and simulates their functionality minus the bitwise part.  I don't know how I should be differentiating between signed and unsigned operations here.

For instance, given registers rd and rs, i need to multiply and put the result in in rd.

for the mult instructions, it's as simple as this:

```
reg[rd] = reg[rs] * reg[rt];
```

What should the multu instruction be? Do I need to be doing bitwise operations on the contents of the registers first?

I also need to do:

-add, addu,
-div, divu
-sub, subu

Is it the same distinction in functionality for all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC in mips assembly the only difference between the signed and unsigned variants is whether or not they set the overflow flag. The multu then, is easier to implement. For the regular, signed, mult you will need to determine if it will overflow the target register and set the flag.

Answer (score 3):

MIPS multiply can't overflow.  Its a 32x32-bit operation with a full 64-bit result.

There is a significant difference between signed and unsigned results, as well.

To simulate these easily in C, you'll need C99 integer types from `<stdint.h>`:

```
uint32_t reg1, reg2; /* Use this type for the registers, normally */
uint32_t hi, lo; /* special MIPS registers for 64-bit products and dividends */    
/* Signed mult instruction: */
int64_t temp = (int64_t)(int32_t)reg1 * (int_64_t)(int32_t)reg2;
hi = (uint32_t)((temp>>32) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
lo = (uint32_t)(temp & 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

The intermediate casts to signed 32-bit types is done so that a cast to signed 64-bit type will sign-extend before multiplication.  The unsigned multiply is similar, except no intermediate cast is needed:

```
/* Unsigned multu instruction: */
uint64_t tempu = (uint64_t)reg1 * (uint64_t)reg2;
hi = (uint32_t)((temp>>32) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
lo = (uint32_t)(temp & 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Comment: @WillLarche It's probably paranoid and unnecessary, but the bitwise ands do guaranteed that the 64-bit value exactly equals the 32-bit value that it's being cast into.  The standards require preserving the original value in that case, no matter what else is going on.  If the prior value is exactly representable in the new type, then that must be the converted value.